# laravel 5.2->Fatal error: Call to a member function posts() on null

Tags: laravel-5

Help me please. I'm a newbie at laravel 5.2. I dont know why Im getting this kind of **error:Fatal error: Call to a member function posts() on null** 
This is my postController file.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class postController extends Controller
{
  public function createPost(Request $request)
  {
    //validation..
    $post= new Post();
    $post->body= $request['body'];
    $request->user()->posts()->save($post);

    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
  }
}
```

this is my Post.php file

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\user');
    }
}
```

my User.php file

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\post');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible that you are not logged in yet of your application that's why when you called:

```
$request->user()->posts()->save($post);
```

user() is still null so there will be no reference to the posts() relation?

EDIT:

To check whether you are logged in you can say:

```
if(Auth::user()){
 //do something here...
}
```

Also I don't think you should save your Post like that. If you want to add the user_id on your post you can say:

```
$post->user()->associate(Auth::user());
$post->save();
```

Comment: How could I check if that user is already Logged in or not. because when I input wrong information you will re-directly back to the log-in page. But when you input the correct information you will be re-directly go to the dashboard..

Comment: this my login function..

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    'email'=> 'required',
    'password'=> 'required'
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request['email'], 'password'=>     $request['password']])){
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
    }

I'm a newbie to laravel. :(